# Unit test for beginner in ASP.NET Core 3 MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing

This is the first time I'm writing a unit test for a .NET Core project. I tried to watch a tutorial and I looked at code online but I can't find a solution for my project.

I have `CompanyController` for the model company use the database `CodingChallegeDBContext` and a service `IPaginatedListService` and I'm trying to write the unit test for the `Index` or `Create` method .

This is the `Company` class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CodingChallenge.Models
{
    //Classe Company
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CompanyLogic { get; set; }

        public Company()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `CompanyController`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CodingChallenge.Data;
using CodingChallenge.Models;
using CodingChallenge.Services;

namespace CodingChallenge.Controllers
{
    public class CompanyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CodingChallengeDBContext _context;

        private readonly IPaginatedListService<Company> _companyService;

        public CompanyController(CodingChallengeDBContext context, IPaginatedListService<Company> companyService)
        {
            _context = context;
            _companyService = companyService;
        }

        public CompanyController()
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var company = from c in _context.Company
                          select c;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                company = company.Where(c => c.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    company = company.OrderByDescending(c => c.CompanyName);
                    break;
                default:
                    company = company.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;

            return View(await PaginatedListService<Company>.CreateAsync(company.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
        }

public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //POST: Creazione
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CompanyCode,CompanyName,CompanyLogic")] Company company)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Controllo se esiste già un'azienda con lo stesso CompanyName e CompanyLogic
                var company_compare = await _context.Company
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CompanyName == company.CompanyName);
                if (company_compare != null)
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "The company " + company.CompanyName + " alredy exist";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

                //Aggiunta della nuova azienda nel DB 
                _context.Add(company);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //Endpoint dettagli dell'azienda creata
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = company.CompanyCode });
            }

            return View(company);
        }
        // some other methods
    }
}
```

This is my `PaginatedlistService`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CodingChallenge.Services
{
    public class PaginatedListService<T> : List<T>, IPaginatedListService<T>
    {
        public PaginatedListService()
        {   
        }

        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedListService(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedListService<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedListService<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the unit test I tried for Create method but it's not working because I can't pass the context and services to the controller Itried to use Mock but I don't understand what to put in "result" to return a view and what to do after

```
[Fact]
        public void CompanyCreate()
        {
            Company company = new Company();
            company.CompanyName = "1";
            company.CompanyLogic = "+1";
            company.CompanyCode = 6;

            CompanyController companycontroller = new CompanyController();

            var result = companycontroller.Create(company);

            Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
        }
---
mock
       Company company = new Company();
       company.CompanyName = "1";
       company.CompanyLogic = "+1";
       company.CompanyCode = 6;
       mock.Mock<CompanyController>()
            .Setup(x => x.Create(company))
            .Returns();
       var controller = mock.Create<Company>();
```

I think I have to use mock but I tried and failed, can anyone write a unit test for the method index or correct the create unit test of company controller so I can understand and write the others unit tests for the other methods or advise me a good and simple tutorial to follow?

Comment: This is a decent question, but it would help if you deleted the methods you aren't trying to test, like the `Create` methods. Also, calling the static method `PaginatedListService<T>.CreateAsync()` will make that service impossible to mock, which in turn will make the test hard to write. One approach would be an `IPaginatedListServiceFactory` interface instead of a static method. That would be easier to mock. That's not perfect, but it's an option.

Comment: I insert the method Create because is simpler to write a unit test, I think, so I tried from that method for my unit test code but didn't work. I know is more difficult the method Index for the service at the end so I asked for that method